# DateTime format is not getting changed in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, date-formatting

I am working on an already developed desktop application in VS 2010 with MS Access database. The application works well in `dd/MM/yyyy` format. But the following code uses `Convert.ToDateTime` which changes `datetime` string in `dd/MM/yyyy` to the system's format and hence gives error.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (Convert.ToDateTime(dtp_Date.Text) - Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["Dat"].ToString())).TotalDays; i++)
{
    double dtSale = _objCashInHand.getSaleSum(Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["Dat"].ToString()).AddDays(j).ToShortDateString().ToString());
    double dtPurchase = _objCashInHand.getPurchaseSum(Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["Dat"].ToString()).AddDays(j).ToShortDateString().ToString());
    double dtEventOrder = _objCashInHand.getEventOrder(Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["Dat"].ToString()).AddDays(j).ToShortDateString().ToString());                        
    double dtCredit = _objCashInHand.getCreditSum(Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["Dat"].ToString()).AddDays(j).ToShortDateString().ToString());
    double dtDebit = _objCashInHand.getDebitSum(Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["Dat"].ToString()).AddDays(j).ToShortDateString().ToString());
    double previousvalue = Convert.ToDouble(dgv_Cash.Rows[(i + 1) - 1].Cells["OpeningAmount"].Value.ToString());
    dgv_Cash.Rows.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["Dat"].ToString()).AddDays(j).ToShortDateString(), dtSale, dtEventOrder, dtPurchase, dtCredit, dtDebit, (previousvalue + Convert.ToDouble(dtSale) + Convert.ToDouble(dtEventOrder) - Convert.ToDouble(dtPurchase) + Convert.ToDouble(dtCredit) - Convert.ToDouble(dtDebit)).ToString());
    j++;
}
```

I tried using `DateTime.ParseExact(dtp_Date.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` but the datetime format is still in system's format.

What do I do to keep the datetime format in dd/MM/yyyy even in the `for loop` for proper working?

Comment: is the system format an epoch?

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` does not changing format, it is parsing your string to internal system representation of `DateTime`, when you see it in `Watch` window it is simply calling `ToString` method, which by default converting it to system format. Object itself does not changing.

Comment: @DLNarasimhan : No, system format is not epoch.

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov Thanks for explaining what `DateTime.ParseExact` does. Is there any way to change the format to dd/MM/yyyy and keep it as datetime to perform the datetime subtraction operation in `for loop` and to use it inside the loop for further operation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify Invariantculture when converting DateTime to string as well.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get you. How to do that? And how it'll help me?